# How to dynamically creating components With Angular 1.5 using a Generic Component?

Tags: angularjs, angular-components, angularjs-components

I need to create a component +/- that contains an "Add button" to allow duplicates of a given component (with its HTML template and logic) and every component has a "Delete button", for that I want to create a generic component which I can pass to it whatever component I want, look at image below [image]

I used transclude, but still not convinced with that, as it's impossible to access the data of every child. This is my code, there is any other way to achieve that?

JS component

```
class AddRemoveComponent {

  /**
   * Inject all the required services.
   *
   */

  constructor() {
    'ngInject'
  }

  $onInit() {
    this.items = []
  }

  /**
   *
   * On add component click.
   */

  addComponent() {
    // TODO
    debugger
    this.items.push({})
  }

  /**
   *
   * On remove component click.
   */

  removeComponent(index) {
    // TODO
    this.items.splice(index, 1)
  }

}

export const addRemoveComponent = {
  template: require('./myiad-add-remove.html'),
  controller: AddRemoveComponent,
  transclude: {
    body: 'iadComponentBody'
  },
  bindings: {
    title: '@',
    items: '='
  }
}
```

HTML component

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary"
            ng-click="$ctrl.addComponent()">
      <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    </button>
    <span class="numeric-stepper">{{ $ctrl.items.length }}</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row margin-top-20" ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
  <div ng-transclude="body"></div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="myiad-remove-bloc col-xs-12 text-center" ng-click="$ctrl.removeComponent($index)">
      <a href="" class="text-uppercase remove-title"><span translate>iadMyIadAddRemove.delete</span> {{ $ctrl.title }}<span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to use it :

```
 <iad-my-iad-add-remove title="TODOLABEL" items="$ctrl.project.realEstateProjectMotivation.realEstateProjectOnSales">
  <iad-component-body>
    <iad-agent-my-iad-project-motivations-how-sale-current-capital-item
      project-references="$ctrl.projectReferences">
    </iad-agent-my-iad-project-motivations-how-sale-current-capital-item>
  </iad-component-body>
</iad-my-iad-add-remove>
```

Thanks :)